# Comparing Data in Files present in two different Directories

Tags: shell, unix, compare

I want to compare the data present in the same files with the same name present in two different directories i.e. I have 10 files present in LND folder and the same 10 files present in WIP folder. My query is that how i can compare the data of the files in these directories. Kindly Help . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your files are textual, what about using [diff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) function?

Comment: i have used diff function but it is not giving any output

Comment: diff will provide no output if files' content is equal. Otherwise it will output the difference.